# Sort alphabetically with Twig

Tags: symfony, sorting, twig

I'm trying to sort a list of categories in alphabetical order. Since this is more of a PHP flaw I'm trying to do this in a way which is described [here](http://obtao.com/blog/2014/06/use-variable-key-twig-array/). I really don't have access to the core files of the system so it need to be done with Twig tags.

**The build in sort filter filters can't be used when using numeric variable as key in a Twig array. This is a very specific problem which is due to the use of the array_merge php function**

I'm trying to incorporate the code in the link into my own code but I'm not able to get it done right.

I'm calling my categories like so:

```
{% for category in shop.categories %}
  {{ category.title }} - {{ category.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I understand the code correct I should do something like:

```
{% set tempArray = {} %}

      {% for category in shop.categories %}
      numeric : {{ category.id }}, text : {{ category.title }} <br />
        {% set tempArray = tempArray | merge({('_' ~ category.numeric):(category.text)}) %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for val in loopArray %}
      {{ tempArray['_' ~ val] }} <br/ >
      {% endfor %}
```

This doens't sort the category names but still the category id's.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/sort.html

Comment: @Med: See my updated answer. The problem is that the array I'm using is using both numeric as text values. I want it to sort on the text values nopt the numeric values.

Comment: It's not enought clear, can you show us some data example from `tempArray`and the expected result please

Comment: You should try to cast the value to a single type before trying to sort

Comment: @Jean: What do you mean with that? I'm still learning twig :(

Comment: Tell whoever has access to the core files to do it with php, this does not belong into the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the link you give (http://obtao.com/blog/2014/06/use-variable-key-twig-array/), it's simply a bad source code which doesn't sort an array.

But have a look there :
[Sorting in the template, in Symfony2: using Twig to sort a collection of objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195862/sorting-in-the-template-in-symfony2-using-twig-to-sort-a-collection-of-objects)

There is no way to sort your array on the category names in twig without create your own filter. Your own filter will do the sort and you will be able to use it in your twig templates.

## ==== do not read but if you want to know what do the bad link ====

In this bad link the guy sort by manually set the order he wants in the line

```
{% set loopValues =  [10,20,30,40] %}
```

In fact all his post is to show that

```
{{ tempArray[val] }} doesn't work with val as a numeric
```

but works with

```
 {{ tempArray['_'~val] }}
```

after a dirty trick (but it would have probably work with just : {{ tempArray[''~val] }} but it's not important the code give by the link is useless...